# Interpolation points data into 2-d shapefile with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, gis, interpolation

#### Background

With point csv data containing `lat`, `lon` and `conc`( the concentration of some air pollutants) representing the monitoring sites, I want to interpolate the original point data into 2-d distribution figure.

Here is my original  point distribution, it's the air quality monitoring network covering China.

[image]

The color are decided by the specific value for each monitoring sites.

I have uploaded the csv data [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7FE0kxAL8kQWkRQRDczaXRCTkE/view?usp=sharing), any one interested can download it.

The different colors of scatter points indicate the varying value among those sites.

The shapefile can be downloaded  [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7FE0kxAL8kQM2E2Qm51RzRUWFU)

#### My attempt

To achieve my target which get a 2-d distribution map from these data, I use scipy.interpolate method.

```
df = pd.read_csv("./the data file")
xt,yt = df["lon"].values, df['lat'].values
zt =  df['value'].values
hfunc = interpolate.interp2d(xt,yt,zt)

xx = np.linspace(110, 120, 40)
yy = np.linspace(25,45, 40)
sh = (40*40,2)
grids = np.zeros(40*40*2).reshape(*sh)
k = 0
for j in range(0,yy.shape[0],1):
    for i in range(0,xx.shape[0],1):
        grids[k] = np.array([xx[i],yy[j]])
        k+=1
xx,yy = zip(*grids)
CONC = np.zeros(len(xx))
for i,(x,y) in enumerate(zip(xx,yy)):
    CONC[i] = hfunc(x,y)

CONC = CONC.reshape(40,40)
```

I have tested the hfunc, but there are some value larger than 40000. The original maximum are no larger than 400. I think there must be some error in my code.

[image]

One spot are much larger than anywhere.

Any advices or guide would be appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the scipy [griddata](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html#scipy.interpolate.griddata) function as described in the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html#multivariate-data-interpolation-griddata).

For example:

```
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

CONC = gridddata((xt,yt), zt, (xx, yy), method='cubic')
```